# Why does this random Next() throw an exception?

Tags: c#, exception, for-loop, random

Hi I'm new to programming and am working from this book. This is an exercise at the end of one of the chapters. But my code throws this exception.

```
        Random rand = new Random();
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = rand.Next(1, 1001);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(numbers[i]);
        }
```

Here is the error:
[image]

Comment: A list is not an array, you probably want to add an item: `numbers.Add(rand.Next(1, 1001));`. [The indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc.aspx) throws this exception if you try to access an item at an index that is >= `list.Count` or < 0.

Comment: it's not random that throws the exception, it's `numbers`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is only called on `Random.Next` when `minValue is greater than maxValue.` as according to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx#ddueExceptionsToggle

Your problem lays with `numbers[i]` as numbers has zero elements, meaning setting `numbers[0] = random.Next(1, 1000);` will return an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` because there is no range yet. Use `numbers.Add(random.Next(1, 1000));` instead

Just a hint, when working with indexers in array type objects (when you use `object[key]`) and for loops you should always use the arrays length as the upper limit of the for loop, like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000 && i < numbers.Count(); i++){
    //Do stuff with i
}
```

In your case the loop will never happen as `i` is always going to be smaller then `numbers.Count()` unless you add items to it

Answer (score 5):

`numbers` is empty, so any index is invalid. Either use `numbers.Add` to add numbers, or better use a pre-sized array. Using a `List` is not necessary here. An array is just fine because the final size is known. It is also faster, although that does not seem to be an issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Your numbers List dosent have any elements yet.

try this:

```
numbers.add(rand.Next(1, 1001));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
numbers.Add(rand.Next(1, 1001));
```

instead of

```
numbers[i] = rand.Next(1, 1001);
```

so you can have a dynamically re-sizing list.

Your list does not have anything at index position `i` so you receive `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. You can only access an item in a collection via its index if there is something there at the given index.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try with this
```

[List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768685/what-is-a-list-in-c-sharp-and-how-does-it-work)

```
   Random rand = new Random();
                List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
                //int [] nums ;
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                    //nums[i] = rand.Next(0, 1000);
                    numbers.Add(rand.Next(0,1000));
                    //numbers[i] = rand.Next(1, 1001);
                }
```

------------------------OR ------------------------------------------

You can use Array also

[Array](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_arrays.htm)

```
Random rand = new Random();
            List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
            int [] nums = new int [1000] ;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                nums[i] = rand.Next(0, 1000);                

            }
```